# Can you link a .so in dotnet?

Tags: linux, .net-core

I have a .NET core project that uses a .so file. I use [DllImport()] to import it. My problem is that this .so has a dependency libtomcrypt.so so it can not locate some symbols(undefined symbol: cipher_descriptor).

I tried importing my .so in C and it works fine if I specify the linker variable -ltomcrypt.

Adding a reference to libtomcrypt.so in the .NET core project did not help because it is a native .so.

Is there any way to link libtomcrypt.so to dotnet?

Comment: You can add it as link to `csproj` file

Comment: I have tried:
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="libtomcrypt">
      <HintPath>\usr\lib\x86_64-linux-gnu\libtomcrypt.so</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

But I get: /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2084,5): warning MSB3246: Resolved file has a bad image, no metadata, or is otherwise inaccessible. Assembly file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtomcrypt.so' could not be opened -- PE image doesn't contain managed metadata. [/home/aron/Desktop/proj/CrossPlatformInterOpTest/CrossPlatformInterOpTest.csproj]

And it still cant finding the symbol

Comment: Nope, using `Reference` is incorrect, try to use `<None Include="path_to_lib"><CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory></None>`

Comment: I tried:
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="\usr\lib\x86_64-linux-gnu\libtomcrypt.so">
      <Link>libtomcrypt.so</Link>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

But it doesnt work... 

Is this how you would do it? If not please explain your solution.

Comment: <None Include="path_to_lib"><CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory></None> doesnt work either...

Comment: If it's *your* .so, you should build it such that it includes dependencies explicitly. What does `ldd your.so` show? If there is no mention of libtomcrypt, it is built incorrectly.

Comment: None of the .so files are built by me...

Answer (score 1):

Try to load your library with `NativeLibrary` first.

```
static class Library
{
const string MyLibrary = "mylibrary";

static Library()
{
    NativeLibrary.SetDllImportResolver(typeof(Library).Assembly, ImportResolver);
}

private static IntPtr ImportResolver(string libraryName, Assembly assembly, DllImportSearchPath? searchPath)
{
    IntPtr libHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    if (libraryName == MyLibrary)
    {
        // Try using the system library 'libmylibrary.so.5'
        NativeLibrary.TryLoad("libmylibrary.so.5", assembly, DllImportSearchPath.System32, out libHandle);
    }
    return libHandle;
}

[DllImport(MyLibrary)]
public static extern int foo();
}
```

[Interacting with native libraries in .NET Core 3.0](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/09/06/interacting-with-native-libraries-in-net-core-3-0/)